# Visual Studio 2005 and .Net framework 1.1

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2005, .net-1.1

Is it possible to create and maintain a .Net framework 1.1 application with Visual Studio 2005?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually there is a MSBuild extension that allow this scenario. It is called [MSBee](http://www.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?ProjectName=MSBee) and you can find it on CodePlex.

> MSBuild Extras – Toolkit for .NET 1.1 “MSBee” is an addition to MSBuild that allows developers to build managed applications using Visual Studio 2005 projects that target .NET 1.1.

Comment: I'm trying to download `MSBee` but its not available on `https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=msbee` can it be downloaded from any other site?

Answer (score 5):

No visual studio 2005 only allows you to work with .net 2.0 and above.

Comment: Only .net2.0; not above, as far as I know.  VS.NET 2008 allows you to work with .NET 2.0 and above.

Comment: You can compile 3.0 code in the vs 2005.  2008 is tailored to it, but it will work with 2k05.

Comment: True, when WCF was released, there was a tool for compiling WCF apps (.NET 3.0) from Visual Studio 2005. +1

Comment: -1 (figuratively).  You CAN do it from vs2005, but you're stuck using VS as a glorified text editor.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, yes, you can, but it's not pretty and you still need .Net 1.1 on the machine.  What you can't do is use Visual Studio to compile or build the site or open the solution file.  You'll have to build it all from the command line.  You'll get either spotty or incorrect intellisense support.

But you can use it like any other text editor to create the source files you need.

Comment: Just like you can use Visual Studio 2005 to write Visual Basic for MS-DOS programs, but the intellisense is even worse :)

Answer (score 2):

No Visual Studio 2005 only works with the 2.0 .Net Framework.  If you want to maintain a 1.1 application you'll need to either use Visual Studio .Net or Visual Studio 2003.

Answer (score 2):

MSBuild Toolkit for .NET 1.1 “MSBee”  compile from vs2005 to net1.1 bot only in webform, dontwork in asp.net...