# Run simple console application made with VS2010 framework 4.0 in a XP computer with framework 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, console

The application is quite simple, it just deletes some local files every configured time period, there is no linq no nothing "new" in the code. If I change the target framework to 2.0 it works well in my computer, but VS2010 doesnt have .net 1.1 as an available target framework.

Is it possible to have it run in an old xp computer that has framework 1.1 (I dont have acces to the computer, cant change its framework). The question is, is there something I can do (in the config file or sln file?) so that it can run in framework 1.1, or do I have to get VS2003 to recreate the console app using 1.1 framework?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228038(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @Shuvra question is about running code on 1.1 and not other way around as your link suggests.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing you can do to get 2.0 or 4.x .Net executable to run with 1.x framework.

You need to compile against 1.x. If you have old VS 2003 around you can use it to recompile solution. If you can't find it - you still can use command line tools (see [Visual Studio 2005 and .Net framework 1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/536992/visual-studio-2005-and-net-framework-1-1) for some info). For simple project with just CS files using csc on target machine to compile the tool from sources may be the easiest route.